# FutureBuilder with Provider: List is not a subtype of type Future<List>

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to create a list of elements in a dynamic way and that the user can modify them naturally, the idea is after inserting the data into an arrangement that shows me that or those elements

```
  FutureBuilder<List<Detalleconcepto>>(
                    future:  provider.listado,
                    builder: (BuildContext context,
                        AsyncSnapshot<List<Detalleconcepto>> snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return _listConceptos(snapshot.data);
                      } else {
                        return Center(
                          child: contenedor(),
                        );
                      }
                    },
                  ),
```

I will leave references of my provider model and my list

```
class ProviderInfo with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Detalleconcepto> _listado = new List<Detalleconcepto>();

  get listado {
    return _listado;
  }

  set listado(List<Detalleconcepto> listado) {
    this._listado = listado;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

```
class Detalleconcepto {
  int idOperacionFinanciera;
  int idTipoConcepto;
  String tipoConcepto;
  double importe;
  String fecha;
  String numeroDocumento;

  Detalleconcepto({
    this.idOperacionFinanciera,
    this.idTipoConcepto,
    this.tipoConcepto,
    this.importe,
    this.fecha,
    this.numeroDocumento,
  });
```

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Future>'

The relevant error-causing widget was
    CreateList

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need a `FutureBuilder` when you have data that is returned in a `Future`, i.e. **asynchronously**.
As the data is returned **synchronously** in your case, you *do not need* a `FutureBuilder`:

```dart
_listConceptos(provider.listado), // instead of FutureBuilder
```